# In Selenium how do i get text "Mahesh Wagh" inside this tag &nbsp;Mahesh Wagh&nbsp;

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath

I have Login into the application and I want to verify my username after login so when I try to find web element of my name I got such html where I'm not [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Il7qO.png)able to get xpath

Kindly let me know how to get xpath of such element

Comment: Which Selenium clients are you using? Java/Python/C#?

Comment: Please read why [a screenshot of code is a bad idea](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors). Paste the code and properly format it instead.

Answer (score 0):

Use this xpath= `.//a[@class='dropdown-toggle']`

and use `element.getText();`

Comment: Thank you #Pratik but dropdown-toggle also have multiple matching element so this xpath wont work

Comment: Use the index of the required dropdown-toggle. Like this (.//a[@class='dropdown-toggle'])[index]

Comment: //Verify Current UserName 
@FindBy(xpath="//a[@class='dropdown-toggle']")
public  WebElement EncorE_Current_user;

Create a method
public Select validateCurrentUser(){
   Select listbox = new Select(EncorE_Current_user);
   // listbox.selectByIndex(4);
    return listbox;
   
  }

and call in my test call 

@Test(priority=4)
 public void EncorECurrentUserTest(){
  Select listbox=homepage.validateCurrentUser();
  listbox.selectByIndex(4);
  System.out.println("Juniper Application Current user is : "+listbox);
 }

Comment: what are you trying to explain here.

Answer (score 0):

Induce `WebDriverWait` And `elementToBeClickable()` And following xpath.

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20);         
WebElement userele=wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//a[./span[@class='glyphicon glyphicon-user']]")));
System.out.println(userele.getText().trim());
```

Comment: I think your xpath won't work as value @Mahesh wants is in tag "a" and is outside of span.

Comment: @Pratik : This is the a tag only which contains the span tag to uniquely identify the element.

Comment: using your xpath I think it will point to the "span" not the "a"

Comment: @Pratik : try with the example which OP posted with my xpath and then confirm.Thanks